# Embed or extend smaller trained LLM to larger ones architecture

Tags: large-language-model, llama

Is it possible, for those currently "popular" publicly available LLM models, to extend an existing, already trained small model (eg. a 7B parameter Llama2-derivate) into the existing architecture of another one (eg. a 70B parameter Llama-2-derivate) ?

My conception of that models is, that the larger ones are sharing the same architecture, but just have more elements by each layer, and maybe more layers - so we can basically spread the 7B model's weights into the 70B architecture, and chose the remaining weights to just add nothing and pass activation identically - so the 70B model will just behabe identical to the 7B model.

After that, the large model can be trained again, but starting from the smaller models checkpoint.

Does this sound feasible?